# Check name of running script file in module

Tags: python, module, program-entry-point

I have 2 app files with import same module:

```
#app1.py
import settings as s
another code

#app2.py
import settings as s
another code
```

I need in module check if running first or second app:

```
#settings.py
#pseudocode
if running app1.py:
   print ('app1')
elif:
   print ('app2')
```

I check module [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/inspect.html) but no idea.

Also I am open for all better solutions.

EDIT: I feel a bit foolish (I guess it is easy)

I try:

```
var = None
def foo(a):
    var = a

print (var)
```

but still `None`.

Comment: Why don't you add some flag or variable in your module which determines whether `app1` or `app2` is calling it?

Comment: Settings.py is almost same for both app, only one variable is different, but this variable is important for 20 anothers. So for avoid duplicates I would like have only one file.

Comment: @FlashTek - Can you explain more, the best in answer?

Comment: Running code in a module based on who imported it is code smell...

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - design application is for me big unknown :( But if explain more, I will be very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure it is possible for an importee to know who imported it. Even if it was, it sounds like code smell to me.

Instead, what you can do is delegate the decision of what actions are to be taken by `app1` and `app2`, instead of having `settings` make that decision.

For example:

`settings.py`

```
def foo(value):
    if value == 'app1': 
        # do something        
    else:
        # do something else
```

`app1.py`

```
from settings import foo    
foo('app1')
```

And so on.

---

To assign within the function and have it reflect on a `global` variable. Example:

`A.py`

```
var = None

def foo(a):
    global var
    var = a

def print_var():
    print(var)
```

`test.py`

```
import A

A.print_var()
A.foo(123)
A.print_var()
```

Output:

```
None
123
```

Note that `global`s aren't recommended in general as a programming practice, so use them as little as possible.

Comment: It looks really nice, tested ;)

Comment: @jezrael Glad I could help :)

Comment: I am afraid  i was not so specific. If i use your function, I need set another variables in `settings.py`. But I cannot do it. I try uggly test `var = ''`, `def check_run_file(a):
    var = a`
    
`print (var) #outside def`. What do you think?

Comment: I guess there is problem function is runned in another `app.py` :(

Comment: @jezrael You should have all configurable variables passed as parameters to `foo` by the scripts that are importing it. So I would say that's the only way. You could do `var=None` initially. It's less ugly.

Comment: @jezrael `def foo(a): global var; var = a` You need to specify that `var` is global - else a local copy is created.

Comment: @jezrael Added an example. This works for me, so make sure you're doing something like this...

Comment: Yes, but I need in file A.py `print(var)` like in last edit in question.

Comment: @jezrael Oh... I see... that isn't possible :( Everything needs to be moved to a function... else it is not possible.

Comment: Your solution not work finally, but i appreciative your patience ;)

Comment: @jezrael Thank you. I hope it works out for you. All the best!

Answer (score 1):

I think your current approach is not the best way do solve your issue. You can solve this, too, by modifying `settings.py` slightly. You have two possible ways to go: either the solution of coldspeed, or using delegates. Either way, you have to store the code of your module inside functions.

Another way to solve this issue would be (depending on the amount of code lines which depend on the app name) to pass a function/delegate to the function as a parameter like this:

```
#settings.py
def theFunction(otherParemters, callback):
    #do something
    callback()

#app1.py
from settings import theFunction
def clb():
    print("called from settings.py")
    #do something app specific here

theFunction(otherParameter, clb)
```

This appears to be a cleaner solution compared to the `inspect` solution, as it allows a better separation of the two modules.

It depends highly on the range of application, whether you should choose the first or the second version; maybe you could provide us with more information about the broader issue you are trying to solve.

Comment: This is identical to my answer, but with more fluff. Would appreciate either changing your answer or removing. Thanks.

Comment: You could retain your second solution, it seems derivative of the first but sufficiently different that I could let it go. Thank you!

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Is this okay?

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, perhaps this is not the *best* way to achieve it. If you do want to though, how about using `sys.argv` to identify the calling module?

app:

```
import settings as s
```

settings:

```
import sys
import os
print sys.argv[0]
# \\path\\to\\app.py
print os.path.split(sys.argv[0])[-1]
# app.py
```

of course, this gives you the file that was originally run from the command line, so if this is part of a further nested set of imports this won't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
import inspect
import os

curframe = inspect.currentframe()
calframe = inspect.getouterframes(curframe, 1)

if os.path.basename(calframe[1][1]) == 'app1.py':
   print ('app1')
else:
   print ('app2')
```

Comment: I get `<frozen importlib._bootstrap>` as the output on python3.4.